# Contact Form HTML, PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I have been learning PHP and have been trying to figure out how to make a contact using HTML and PHP, I have got the contact form down but when I try to submit the form it brings up a blank white page (email.php) with no error or success messages.

This is my HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="email.php">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" value="">
                </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name-last" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="">
                 </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
                 <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $name = $_POST['name-last'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'ronniegurr7@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body ="From: $name\n $name-last\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if last name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name-last']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your last name';
        }   

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }
// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$name-last&& !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

I am using Hostinger to test my website! If anyone could help with this I would be very grateful.

Comment: you have 2x inputs bearing the same `name="name"` for one thing.

Comment: So if I change one to name="last-name" will this work? @Fred-ii-

Comment: give it a go and see

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nope I am still getting a plain white page when hitting the send button!

Comment: If all your code does is `$result = "…";`  then naturally nothing will be output. And no, we can't guess if there's any more code. `isset` is also less suited to debugging than a few `print_r` statements, btw.

Comment: You say no errors, but is your error reporting on..? -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`. Also, read what mario said above.

Comment: Make this ` $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';` into this: ` echo ('<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'); and this `$result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';` into `echo('<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>'");` That will show you something on the page.

Comment: @jonmrich I have changed $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>'; and $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>'; To what you have commented but this is still leaving a white page!

Comment: But you're saying you want to show something on the page. Nothing will show on the page unless you use `echo` or `print`

Comment: I have managed to get the form working now but I am running in to trouble now where if they leave a filed that needs to be filled in it doesn't redirect them back to the form page and leaves them on a white page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last if statement makes sure that name-last is set... But you never define it. You redefine name from being $_POST['name'] to $_POST['name-last'].

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $name = $_POST['name-last'];
```

to

```
 $name = $_POST['name']; // for the first name field
 $name-last = $_POST['name-last']; // for the last name field
```

You need to check to make sure that on the form all of your inputs have the desired unique name that you want to call on within the POST superglobal. The labels don't do anything in this case.

Also, just for future debugging purposes, you may want to wrap each of the variables you are checking in isset() to be safe.

```
if(!isset($errName) && isset($name-last) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage) && !isset($errHuman){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this line maybe it cause the problem change the second variable

```
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $name = $_POST['name-last'];
```